# CodeIgniter best way to handle forms

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, codeigniter

The reason I'm asking this question is that I already built 50% of a website without using a PHP framework. Now I just started using CodeIgniter with the purpose of using less code and making a more secure website and I was hoping there was a nice option to handle forms...

However I came to the following options:

## Option 1

In my view file I use a form like this:

```
<?php echo form_open(‘form’); ?>

<input type=“text” name=“username” value=”” size=“50” />

<div><input type=“submit” value=“Submit” /></div>

</form>
```

Then I have a controller that handles the form and, if necessary, I use a model to insert data for example.
The advantage is that it’s simple and not much work is needed. I can even generate my own form using a website like http://formigniter.org/app/.
Big problem for me is that this method always reloads the view page and I don’t want to refresh a page.

## Option 2

The other option is to use jQuery/Ajax.

In my view I have a simple input field:

```
<input type=“text” id=“username” name=“username” size=“50” />
```

And I have some javascript code:

```
  $(’#username’).change(function() {

    var post_data = {
      ‘message’: $(”#username”).val()
    };

    $.ajax({
      type: “POST”,
      url: “<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/registratie_c/insertByajax”,
      data: post_data,
      success: function(message) {
          alert(message);
      }
    });
  });
```

In my controller I need to get the data like this:

```
$data[‘message’] = $this->input->post(‘message’);
```

After that I can do whatever I want.
Big advantage is that I don’t have to reload my page, as a user types the data is being sent.
My problem here is that it’s a lot of work. I have to write some javascript to get the data from the different input fields. In my controller I have to do this another time, output it back again and there’s no form generator.

My issue/question is, which one do you prefer?
And isn’t there a solution that’s simple but also let’s you post data on the fly? The above 2 options still feel pretty undeveloped.
I don't want to make a website using .NET MVC 4, but I think it does support things like this.

p.s. I do know there’s an option to post a whole form using jQuery serialize…

Comment: If the form information is interacting with your database then i would suggest doing your validation on the server side - and codeigniter makes that simple.

Comment: The form mostly will interact with the database. But in both options the validation will be done in the controller/model.

My question is, how should I send my data from the view to the controller? Using option 1 or option 2 or another option?